# Customize the appender that will manage the logger message

Tags: java, logback, log4j2

I want to create three appenders: *file*, *console* and *database*. Besides I have stored in database three variables: *info*, *error* and *warn*, whose values ​​correspond to one of the above appenders.

So, when I will run the following statement:

```
Logger.info ("bla bla bla")
```

I need get the current value of *info* in the database dynamically and display the message on the right appender (*file*, *console* or *database*).

With **Logback**:

**1.** I need to create an entire [DBAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#DBAppender) class (like [this](http://www.techques.com/question/1-7659837/Logback-dbAppender-Custom-SQL)), because I don't want to store the information in three different tables (only in one).

**2.** Capture the value of the database for *info* seems simple thanks to the [filters](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html#yourOwnFilter). So I could include the filter in each appender and, based on the value of *info*, I could decide whether or not to use "the current appender".

With **Log4j 2**:

**1.** I can use [JDBCAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#JDBCAppender) (instead of having to create a new class).

**2.** How do I create a customized [filter](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html) that serve me to fetch the value of *info* in the database, and help me decide if I should or should not use one of the appenders (*file*, *console* or *database*)?

The question is:

Is there any way to make it easier the *"first point of Logback"* or to carry out the *"second point of Log4j2"*?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution to my problem. In **logback.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration>
<configuration>

   <!-- Loads the datasource properties file -->
   <property resource="datasource.properties" />

   <!-- Directory where log files will be stored -->
   <property name="LOG_DIRECTORY" value="/tmp" />

   <!-- Appenders -->
   <appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
      <filter class="com.myproject.logback.ConsoleFilter" />
      <encoder>
         <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%-5level.%msg - %class.%method : %line]%n</pattern>
      </encoder>
   </appender>

   <appender name="database" class="com.myproject.logback.CustomDBAppender">
      <filter class="com.myproject.logback.DBFilter" />
      <connectionSource class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DataSourceConnectionSource">
         <dataSource class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
            <driverClass>${jdbc.driverClass}</driverClass>
            <jdbcUrl>${jdbc.jdbcUrl}</jdbcUrl>
            <databaseName>${jdbc.databaseName}</databaseName>
            <user>${jdbc.user}</user>
            <password>${jdbc.password}</password>
        </dataSource>
     </connectionSource>
  </appender>

  <appender name="file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
     <filter class="com.myproject.logback.FileFilter" />
     <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- Rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_DIRECTORY}/mylog-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.txt</fileNamePattern>
        <!-- Keep 10 days of history -->
        <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
     </rollingPolicy>
     <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%-5level.%msg - %class.%method : %line]%n</pattern>
     </encoder>
  </appender>

  <!-- Logger for my project -->
  <logger name="com.myproject" additivity="false" level="all">
     <appender-ref ref="console" />
     <appender-ref ref="database" />
     <appender-ref ref="file" />
  </logger>

  <root level="info">
     <appender-ref ref="console" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```

Now **CustomDBAppender.java**:

```
public class CustomDBAppender extends DBAppenderBase<ILoggingEvent> {

    protected String insertSQL;

    // Indices of the fields of the table in which the logging information is stored
    private static final int EVENTTIME_INDEX     = 1;
    private static final int MESSAGE_INDEX       = 2;
    private static final int LOGGER_INDEX        = 3;
    private static final int LEVEL_INDEX         = 4;
    private static final int CALLER_CLASS_INDEX  = 5;
    private static final int CALLER_METHOD_INDEX = 6;
    private static final int CALLER_LINE_INDEX   = 7;
    private static final int TRACE_INDEX         = 8;

    static final StackTraceElement EMPTY_CALLER_DATA = CallerData.naInstance();

    @Override
    public void append (ILoggingEvent eventObject) {

       Connection connection = null;
       PreparedStatement insertStatement = null;
       try {
          connection = connectionSource.getConnection();
          connection.setAutoCommit (false);

          insertStatement = connection.prepareStatement (getInsertSQL());

          // Inserting the event in database
          synchronized (this) {
             subAppend (eventObject, connection, insertStatement);
          }
          secondarySubAppend (eventObject, connection, 1);

          connection.commit();

       } catch (Throwable sqle) {
          addError("problem appending event", sqle);
       } finally {
          DBHelper.closeStatement (insertStatement);
          DBHelper.closeConnection (connection);
       }
    }

    @Override
    protected Method getGeneratedKeysMethod() {
       return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getInsertSQL() {
       return insertSQL;
    }

    @Override
    protected void secondarySubAppend (ILoggingEvent eventObject,
                       Connection connection, long eventId) throws Throwable {}

    @Override
    public void start() {
       insertSQL = CustomDBAppender.buildInsertSQL();
       super.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void subAppend (ILoggingEvent event, Connection connection,
                      PreparedStatement insertStatement) throws Throwable {

       bindLoggingEventWithInsertStatement (insertStatement, event);
       bindCallerDataWithPreparedStatement (insertStatement, event.getCallerData());

       int updateCount = insertStatement.executeUpdate();
       if (updateCount != 1) {
          addWarn("Failed to insert loggingEvent");
       }
    }

    void bindCallerDataWithPreparedStatement (PreparedStatement stmt,
            StackTraceElement[] callerDataArray) throws SQLException {

       StackTraceElement caller = extractFirstCaller (callerDataArray);

       stmt.setString (CALLER_CLASS_INDEX, caller.getClassName());
       stmt.setString (CALLER_METHOD_INDEX, caller.getMethodName());
       stmt.setString (CALLER_LINE_INDEX, Integer.toString (caller.getLineNumber()));
    }

    void bindLoggingEventWithInsertStatement (PreparedStatement stmt,
            ILoggingEvent event) throws SQLException {

       stmt.setTimestamp (EVENTTIME_INDEX, new Timestamp (event.getTimeStamp()));
       stmt.setString (MESSAGE_INDEX, event.getFormattedMessage());
       stmt.setString (LOGGER_INDEX, event.getLoggerName());
       stmt.setString (LEVEL_INDEX, event.getLevel().toString());

       if (event.getThrowableProxy() != null && 
           event.getThrowableProxy().getStackTraceElementProxyArray() != null)
          stmt.setString (TRACE_INDEX, ThrowableProxyUtil.asString (event.getThrowableProxy()));
       else
          stmt.setString (TRACE_INDEX, null);
    }

    private static String buildInsertSQL () {

       return "INSERT INTO mylogtable "
            + " (eventtime, message, logger, level, callerclass, callermethod, callerline, trace) "
            + "VALUES "
            + "(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    }

    private StackTraceElement extractFirstCaller (StackTraceElement[] callerDataArray) {

       StackTraceElement caller = EMPTY_CALLER_DATA;
       if (hasAtLeastOneNonNullElement (callerDataArray))
          caller = callerDataArray[0];

       return caller;
    }

    private boolean hasAtLeastOneNonNullElement (StackTraceElement[] callerDataArray) {
       return callerDataArray != null && callerDataArray.length > 0 && callerDataArray[0] != null;
    }
 }
```

Every **filter** has a similar structure, for this reason I only show one, **FileFilter.java**:

```
public class FileFilter extends Filter<ILoggingEvent> {

   @Override
   public FilterReply decide (ILoggingEvent event) {

      try {
         // I have in a database table something like this:
         //    Level   -   Appender
         //    ERROR         FILE
         //    DEBUG        CONSOLE
         //    ...

         // Here I check with a service if "the actual logger level"
         // [event.getLevel()] in the previous database table, is set
         // to record their messages with the "current appender"

         if (thePreviousCondition == true)
            return FilterReply.ACCEPT;

         return FilterReply.DENY;

      } catch (Exception e) {
         return FilterReply.DENY;
      }
   }
}
```

The previous code is a simplification of "my real code", basically because I have in **CustomDBAppender** one table for each logger level, instead of a only one "general table". Besides I used **REDIS** to cache the values of Level-Appender to avoid search always in database.

Also I only define 4 levels in my application: *ERROR*, *WARN*, *INFO* and *DEBUG*. So by a enum I carry out the equivalence between the level of Logback and the level of my application.

However, this is the skeleton of what has helped me to do what I intended.

Answer (score 2):

Log4j2 supports filters, I believe fairly similar to Logback. It sounds like you are looking for filtering based on level, you can do this with the [ThresholdFilter](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html#ThresholdFilter).

Or perhaps you are looking for something like the [RoutingAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RoutingAppender) (see FAQ for an [extended example](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#separate_log_files))? This allows you to configure multiple appenders and dynamically route log events to different appenders based on the ThreadContext map.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I do not understand how I can using the ThresholdFilter filter to get the value of "info" from database previously.  For example, today I have stored in "info" the "file appender", so that all Logger.info must be sent to a file, but tomorrow it could store the database appender. All appenders have the same filter, so today for Logger.info should discard: database appender and console appender, while tomorrow should discard: file appender and console appender

Comment: I added the RoutingAppender suggestion to my answer. I hope this does what you are looking for.

Comment: When I was reading the Log4j2 documentation I saw the option of using the ThreadContext however, I found it very annoying to have to be updating their values ​​"manually" for this reason I liked the approach Logback (masking the database query in "my own filter", so that if "tomorrow" the "data source" changes, just have to change it in one place).  Is there a way in Log4j2 to do the same with the ThreadContext?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar enough with Logback to know how that works. Perhaps you can raise a feature request for this on the Log4j2 issue tracker?

Comment: Curiously I read in "Log4j The complete manual" (in "Writting your own filter" section) that the version 1.2 allowed the same functionality than Logback. Something like this: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html#yourOwnFilter.

Comment: In that case Log4j2 may provide it but I just don't know how. If you raise this on the Log4j2 issue tracker, other folks in the Log4j2 team may be able to help you.