# Spring boot logging into mysql database

Tags: spring-boot, logging, log4j

I have to put all the log data (i.e., debug, info, error) into mysql database instead of to file/console. 
I read the spring boot documentation but I didn't see any configuration related to database for logging.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html

Also tried the following link but its also not working. 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_database.htm

Can anyone help me to do this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I read the spring boot documentation but I didn't see any
>   configuration related to database for logging.

Because spring boot hands off that functionality to logging framework  (slf4j + logback/log4j etc). So you need to configure your logging framework accordingly using it's configuration file (eg: logback.xml, logback-spring.xml, logback.groovy etc). Default logging frameworks in Spring boot is slf4j+logback. So checkout how you can use DBAppender.

## For Logback

https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#DBAppender
http://learningviacode.blogspot.com/2014/01/writing-logs-to-database.html
[Log to database with LogBack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007132/log-to-database-with-logback)
https://medium.com/@chakrar27/storing-log-data-in-postgresql-using-logback-db-appender-292891a9918

**1. create logback.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="db" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
        <connectionSource
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource">
            <driverClass>org.postgresql.Driver</driverClass>
            <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/simple</url>
            <user>postgres</user>
            <password>root</password> <!-- no password -->
        </connectionSource>
    </appender>

    <!-- the level of the root level is set to DEBUG by default. -->
    <root level="TRACE">
        <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
        <appender-ref ref="db" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

**2. Create the 3 tables**

logging_event

logging_event_property

logging_event_exception

They must exist before DBAppender can be used

## For Log4J

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#JDBCAppender

## For Log4J2

http://smasue.github.io/log4j2-spring-database-appender

Comment: Thank you. I have tried"Logback" now. Working fine with default tables but creating custom table/fields really hard.

Comment: Your connection string must be legitimate .. or you may be a "dialect" error.  Make sure your connection string is correct/working before debugging an dialect issues.  #learnedTheHardWay

Comment: Yes, customizing logback is much harder than other frameworks I've seen.

Comment: I found the script for the db tables in `postgresql.sql` of `logback-classic-1.2.3.jar`. Full folder path `logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!\ch\qos\logback\classic\db\script\`

Comment: Should the logback.xml file be created in the resources folder or the project root directory?