# Logback Log to DB no Exception but doesn't work

Tags: java, sql, mariadb, logback

I'm trying to look to a DB and the console with **Logback**.

Based on [the documention](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html) I need these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE mybb.logging_event (
    timestamp BIGINT,
    formatted_message TEXT,
    logger_name VARCHAR(255),
    level_string VARCHAR(255),
    reference_flag SMALLINT,
    caller_filename VARCHAR(255),
    caller_class VARCHAR(255),
    caller_method VARCHAR(255),
    caller_line CHAR,
    event_id INT
);

CREATE TABLE mybb.logging_event_property  (
    event_id INT,
    mapped_key VARCHAR(255),
    mapped_value TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE mybb.logging_event_exception (
    event_id INT,
    i SMALLINT,
    trace_line VARCHAR(255)
);
```

And based on  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46853433/spring-boot-logging-into-mysql-database) I need this logback.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="db" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
        <connectionSource class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource">
            <driverClass>org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver</driverClass>
            <url>jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/mybb</url>
            <user>root</user>
            <password>root</password> <!-- no password -->
        </connectionSource>
    </appender>

    <!-- the level of the root level is set to DEBUG by default. -->
    <root>
        <!--appender-ref ref="stdout" /-->
        <appender-ref ref="db" />
        <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
        <level value="debug" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

The `ConsoleAppender` works but the `DBAppender` doesn't work at all. There is no exception on the console or something else - the database is empty. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc I used seems to be outdated. After a long look in the right repo I found this beauty here:

```
# Logback: the reliable, generic, fast and flexible logging framework.
# Copyright (C) 1999-2010, QOS.ch. All rights reserved.
#
# See http://logback.qos.ch/license.html for the applicable licensing 
# conditions.

# This SQL script creates the required tables by ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender.
#
# It is intended for MySQL databases. It has been tested on MySQL 5.1.37 
# on Linux


BEGIN;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS logging_event_property;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS logging_event_exception;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS logging_event;
COMMIT;


BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE logging_event 
  (
    timestmp         BIGINT NOT NULL,
    formatted_message  TEXT NOT NULL,
    logger_name       VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
    level_string      VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
    thread_name       VARCHAR(254),
    reference_flag    SMALLINT,
    arg0              VARCHAR(254),
    arg1              VARCHAR(254),
    arg2              VARCHAR(254),
    arg3              VARCHAR(254),
    caller_filename   VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
    caller_class      VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
    caller_method     VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
    caller_line       CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    event_id          BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
  );
COMMIT;

BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE logging_event_property
  (
    event_id          BIGINT NOT NULL,
    mapped_key        VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
    mapped_value      TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(event_id, mapped_key),
    FOREIGN KEY (event_id) REFERENCES logging_event(event_id)
  );
COMMIT;

BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE logging_event_exception
  (
    event_id         BIGINT NOT NULL,
    i                SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    trace_line       VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(event_id, i),
    FOREIGN KEY (event_id) REFERENCES logging_event(event_id)
  );
COMMIT;
```

With this it works like a charm. If somebody else need scripts for different DB's here is the link: https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-classic/src/main/resources/ch/qos/logback/classic/db/script/